# how is LayoutParams.FLAG_SCALED used

Tags: android, android-layout

There is very little information about this flag. The documentation on the developer site says.

> "Window flag: a special mode where the layout parameters are used to perform scaling of the surface when it is composited to the screen."

Does this mean if I have a WebView at one pixel dimension, that it could be scaled up or down to the screen resolution?

This would be a cool trick for application porting.